# How to pass context or generate test case for context in botium-cli

Tags: bots, testcase

I am trying to generate test cases for context for Dialogflow. When i run command this command, it does not generate test cases for contexts(intents)

```
botium-cli import dialogflow-conversations
```

My agent has this type of structure

```
Default Welcome
    |
Collect info
    |
    Name
       |
       Email
        |
        Project Requirements
```

When i run command to generate test cases, Botium only generate test case for Name inputs. Botium only generates these files for collect-info intent and their contexts:

```
Collect-Info-Name.convo.txt
Collect-Info_input.utterances.txt
Collect-Info_output_0.utterances.txt
Name_input.utterances.txt
Name_output_0.utterances.txt
```

Help me with this. Thanks

Comment: can you prepare and share a dialogflow workspace to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for quick response @FlorianTreml,
Can you please provide me with your Google account id for Dialogflow? I will add you as developer so that you can check.

Comment: ftreml "at" gmail.com

Comment: @FlorianTreml I have added you as developer. Please go through our agent and help us further. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, but there was a Bug in Botium-CLI. This has been fixed now in a Github branch (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli/tree/bugfix/-BOT-584-core-botium-cli-dialogflow-impor), and it will be part of the next release.
You can already use it if you check out the bugfix branch instead of the master from Github:

```
> git clone https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli.git && git checkout bugfix/-BOT-584-core-botium-cli-dialogflow-impor
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per you mentioned, I have tried with replacing these two file: **dialogflowintents.js** and **index.js** in import directory but it did not work. Also i tried with replacing whole **botium-cli** directory but that thing also is not working for me.

Comment: I verified it by letting it run with the Dialogflow agent you provided access for me. Convo files and utterances were generated successfully, matching the dialog structure. Exchanging the files is probably not enough, build has also to be done (depending on how you use it).

Comment: Thanks, It has solve my problem, Actually i was replacing **dialogflowintents.js** and **index.js** in root directory but they had to be replaced in current directory. So now its working fine.